# Website Design Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, web, opencart, e-commerce

I'm looking into designing a shopping cart protein website.

I'm looking forward in desiging the front-end layout but back-end I have no idea in and was wondering how i can setup a shopping cart system for customers to pay with paypal/credit or debit card?

Comment: Better you can ask this question in quora instead here...

Comment: one google search is all it took.. Free open-source php backend shopping cart.. https://www.opencart.com/
(edit;)
I just notised you have it TAGGED with opencart... if you have no clue what you're doing, hire someone.

Comment: Look at shopify.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use a CMS like WordPress or Joomla!. It will save you a lot of time and you can still customize it to fit your needs. You can have an e-commerce site built in 20 minutes using Joomla! and Hikashop. If you are not interested in a platform then you can just use PHP or Java as your server side language and build it from scratch.

Comment: I could use wordpress but how would i design a shopping cart system with this? a plugin?

Comment: Yes, all you would need to do is install an e-commerce plugin like WooCommerce. It is pretty straightforward in WordPress, unlike Joomla! which has a moderate learning curve.

Comment: awesome do you know if i can design my site and not select a wooocmmerece theme but still use the shopping sysytem?

Comment: You can use any theme you like without using a WooCommerce ready theme. You can build an e-commerce solution using WordPress in a matter of clicks.